# How to create smooth edges in CSS border shape?

Tags: html, css

Here is my screen shot,
You can able see the blurred edges on the top-left side,
I am new to CSS,
Please provide solution for this problem.

[image]

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #9966ff;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.shape:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1500px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 250px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-left: 1500px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: How to create smooth edges?

Comment: please provide your code?

Comment: <html>
<head>

<style>
.shape
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#9966ff;
outline:1px solid transparent;
box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.shape:after
{
content:'';
border-right:1500px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-top:250px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
border-left:1500px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
float:right;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="shape">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I posted my code as answer below, so please kindly check it and provide your solutions.

Comment: The jagged line is probably related to the [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) of your monitor.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #9966ff;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 56px;
}
.shape:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1500px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 340px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-left: 1500px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: But the border-radius  changing the shape.

Comment: I need the shape remains same

Answer (score 0):

Inside shape use style "border-radius:15px;"

Comment: Still it some what blur

Comment: I need picture perfect(100% smooth) line

Comment: adjust it by changing pixel and set it according to your requirement.

Comment: Is there is any other easy way to create this shape via CSS?